# Python unit test - NameError: name '' is not defined

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest

Using Python 3.x. 
When running the test case for the following code, I get the error - 
`NameError: name 'TEST_VAR' is not defined`. I am attaching the file to test, the yaml file the code is reading, and the unit test file.

FileToTest.py: https://pastebin.com/d9QQiVSD

```
from os import path
from typing import TextIO
from yaml import load as yload, SafeLoader

TEST_FILE = "test.yaml"


def retreiveFilePath(fpath, fname, write_mode=False) -> TextIO:
    filePath = open("%(path)s/%(filename)s" % {
        "path": fpath,
        "filename": fname
    },
        "w" if write_mode else "r"
    )
    return filePath


def methodToTest(val1, val2) -> str:
    return "%(base)s/%(name)s/%(version)s.jar" % {
        "base": TEST_VAR["var1"]["var12"],
        "name": val1,
        "version": val2
    }


def method1() -> TextIO:
    try:
        filePath = retreiveFilePath(path.dirname(__file__), TEST_FILE)
        configReturn = yload(filePath.read())
        return configReturn
    except Exception as e:
        print("Failure, ", e)
    return None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        TEST_VAR = method1()
    except Exception as err:
        exit_code = 1
    exit(exit_code)
```

yaml File:

```
var1:
  var12: someVal12
  var13: someVal13
var2:
  var21: someVal21
```

test case: https://pastebin.com/crLymTHb

```
import unittest

from mock import patch

import FileToTest

class TestFile(unittest.TestCase):

    def test__get_artifact_url(self):
        val1 = "FName"
        val2 = "LName"
        resp = "someVal12/FName/LName.jar"
        target_resp = FileToTest.methodToTest(val1, val2)
        self.assertEqual(resp, target_resp)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

What would be the correct way to handle this situation? I tried using patch but to no vain.

Comment: You're unit test doesn't execute the `if __name__ == '__main__' ` block inside FileToTest.py, because FileToTest is only being imported, not executed. So you need to make sure `TEST_VAR` is defined even when FileToTest is not the file being run. If FileToTest functions are supposed to runnable from an import, then your testing has successfully revealed a bug.

Comment: Is mocking the solution to this? Can you please explain it via code on how to handle this?

Comment: Either initialise `TEST_VAR` in your unittest script, or initialise it in `FileToTest.py` not in an `if __name__` statement, or change your function so it does not require `TEST_VAR` to be already initialised.

Comment: If I add ```TEST_VAR = FileToTest1.method1()``` to the main method of TestFile, I still get the same error, as the call goes to the Exception of method1.

Answer (score 0):

There are two layers of variables in python, local and global. When you reference a variable in a function it only exists in that function unless you make it a global variable. You can either pass the variable as a parameter in the functions or reference global. To do this you can either move the TEST_VAR outside of the main function, or above write

```
global TEST_VAR
```

Comment: I added ```global TEST_VAR``` in FileToTest.py. Still same error.

Comment: Try adding global to both where you define it, so the main function, and methodToTest.

Comment: If that does not work, try moving the code from main in FileToTest out of the main function and leave it in the executor

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. Maybe I'm declaring it wrong. Can you please tell by code lines how exactly you are suggesting? Moreover, I don't want the actually execute method1(), and instead return a mock key-value pair response for TEST_VAR.

Comment: Either add global TEST_VAR to lines 19 and 38. Or remove the main function and unindent all the code in main. If you don't want to execute method1 then define TEST_VAR on line 4 and overwrite it later on in the code

Comment: Declaring TEST_VAR as global and initializing it with an empty string (both in the main class) fixed the issue.